# Reference Object Properties in a Kendo UI Modal View

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

My problem relates to the Kendo UI Modal view 
I have a listview, that when a listview item is clicked I want it to go to a modal view with more of the clicked items attributes there.
I can access the listview item and store it in a JS variable. However my question is how do I reference the object then in the html5 for the modal view?
My code looks like this  [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPzVu/7/) 
The object is currently stored in the variable 'clicked'

 The only way I could think of defining the modal view as is

```
 <div id="modal" data-role="modalview" style="width: 95%; height: 95%;">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a data-align="right" data-click="closeModalView" data-role="button">Close</a>            
        </div>       
    </div>
    #: clicked.name #
</div>
```

But then I cant reference the clicked variables attributes......
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #: # thingy works only inside a template. In order for you to use the values outside of the template you nee to store the data in a different variable available in the global name space and use that variable inside the modal view. I have fixed your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kendomobile/MPzVu/8/

I create a span inside the modal view  `<span id="modalview-text"> </span>` and in the click event, stored the value inside a global variable ( `listItemclicked` ) and wrote the variable inside the span using this jQuery code:  `$('#modalview-text').text(listItemclicked.name);`

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="eventfeed" data-click="listViewClick"></ul> 
        <div id="modal" data-role="modalview" style="width: 95%; height: 95%;">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a data-align="right" data-click="closeModalView" data-role="button">Close</a>            
        </div>       
    </div>
            <span id="modalview-text"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Another way of doing this is to use MVVM and bind the object listItemclicked to an HTML element inside the modal window so that when the data changes, modal windows automatically reflects the changes.

Comment: Thanks, Ill have a look at that for future problems.

Comment: Mike, just incase if you dont know, you can upvote the answer along with marking it as answer if the answer really solved your problem.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote lol.
One problem I am facing is rendering an image using this method.
My debugger shows me I am doing it like this: 
<img height="100" width="100" id="mv-pic">Imageurl</img>
Although the actual image just appears as a box?

Comment: The image url should be rendered inside the src attribute not as you have posted above. <img height="100" width="100" id="mv-pic" src="#:Imageurl#"></img> .